# Want to see inserted data in SQL Server with column name and its value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Want to see inserted data in SQL Server with each column name and its value, I am using stored procedure for `INSERT / UPDATE` like this.

For example, mode = 'insert':

```
Insert into Employee_table(Name, Age, DOB, salary) 
values (@Name, @Age, @DOB, @salary)
```

Now I want to see like :

```
insert into Employee_table(Name, Age, DOB, salary)
values ('Arun', 23, 12-12-2016, 10000)
```

Comment: These variables would have a value and context only if the stored procedure were actually being run.  Couldn't you just check your table to see if the correct records were inserted?

Comment: If you **want** to see this, you'll have to do your own "parameter-replacement" magic since SQL Server will ***NEVER*** actually get to see that second version of your `INSERT` - SQL Server will receive the query *with* the parameter, and a list of parameters and there values, and there's never any replacement of `@Age` by `23` in the actual SQL code ...

Comment: Thanks for your Information

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server directly doesn't provide any UI to capture the real time values for all the DML/DDL operations. However this can be worked around as shown below,

1. Creating the dynamic queries with all DML statements and have a Print statement at the end of each statement (which is a tedious job though)
2. Login to SQL Profiler and customize/filter the output to trace the SQL statements

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange to me, but I think you can try:

```
Insert into Employee_table(Name, Age, DOB, salary) 
OUTPUT inserted.*
values (@Name, @Age, @DOB, @salary)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    Try this.


    Create Procedure Proc_Insert_Employee_Table
    (
      @Name varchar(50),
      @Age int, 
      @DOB date, 
      @salary int
    )
    as
    Begin

    set nocount on

        Insert into Employee_table(Name, Age, DOB, salary) 
    values (@Name, @Age, @DOB, @salary)

    print 'Insert into Employee_table(Name, Age, DOB, salary) 
    values ('+@Name+','+cast(@Age as varchar)+','+cast(@DOB as varchar)+','+cast(@salary as varchar)+')'

END
```

Comment: Always Welcome.